# Nginx php site and node app on different port

Tags: nginx

I have installed nginx and configured php and mysql in my vps. My home page exist at /var/www/html. and it is working correctly when I access it form any computer.

Now I installed nodejs and set a simple hello world accoring to [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

my nginx defauls file is

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ = 404 $uri.html $uri/index.html @app;      

    #proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

}

location @app {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

My problem is either my php files are served or node files are served, while I want, http://ipaddress:80 whould serve my php files, and http://ipaddress:3000 should serve my nodejs app.

I am using pm2 node module.
I am very-2 new to nginx.
Thanks

Comment: try to add 2 seperate server blocks, with different ports.

Comment: @Ali, how can i do this. I actually have very less idea of nginx.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root        /var/www/html;
    index       index.php;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 3000;
    listen [::]:3000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```